# SQL Server datetime comparison in different formats

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query in which I will be passing `dd/mm/yyyy` but the SQL query requires `mm/dd/yyyy`.

How can I enable this query to take `dd/mm/yyyy` and display the correct result based on the correct format? What is the best way to achieve this thing in SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT int_ExchangeRateId, int_LocationId, dtm_Date
FROM ExchangeRate
WHERE dtm_Date >= '01/02/2006' AND dtm_Date <= '12/02/2006' AND int_LocationId = 98
```

THIS WORKS CORRECTLY:

```
SELECT int_ExchangeRateId, int_LocationId,dtm_Date 
FROM ExchangeRate 
WHERE CAST(dtm_Date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2006-02-02' AND '2006-02-12' 
  AND int_LocationId=98
```

Comment: Use `date` parameters rather than string parameters. If you must use strings at least use an unambiguous format such as `yyyymmdd`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I just had to comment, I find it worrying you have the data type prefixing the name of your field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the query I would use dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. As to the output see kalyan's answer.

**EDIT:** To summarise the comments below (thanks to marc_s) it is necessary to use the format `YYYYMMDD` when the time part is not included *unless* you are using the new date types `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Actually - that format is **not** language-independent.... you need to use `YYYYMMDD` (or: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`)

Comment: @marc_s - I understood `YYYY-MM-DD` format to be neutral in so far as the ISO 8601 standard defines a calendar date (http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format) and the OP hadn't mentioned the need for a time part. I appreciate this might not be the case for SQL Server 2008; I'll have to have another look at BOL :)

Comment: no, **it's not neutral** - try this: `set language british .... SELECT CAST('2011-08-26' AS DATETIME)` - **THIS WILL FAIL!** - The language-neutral ISO-8601 format is `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes) - trust me!

Comment: It's quite odd - but if you add the time portion, the format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` with the dashes. If you leave out the time portion, you **must not** use any dashes (use `YYYYMMDD`)

Comment: Also: strangely enough, if you cast to a `DATE`, then `YYYY-MM-DD` works again - even with British English as your language.... `SET LANGUAGE British .... SELECT CAST('2011-08-26' AS DATE)` converts just fine...

Comment: That is strange, thanks for the additional information. I found a couple of blog posts on the subject which I found interesting: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/12/08/unambiguous-date-formats-t-sql-tuesday-001.aspx and http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/05/date-format-inconsistency-yyyy-mm-dd-or-yyyymmdd-when-2007-04-10-is-4th-october.aspx

Comment: @marc_s: YYYY-MM-DD is safe for the new date/time data types introduced in SQL Server 2008:`date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` but it's unsafe for the old types: `[small]datetime`.

Comment: If the madness bothers you, consider voting on this suggestion: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=290971

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [DateTime Formating](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) for this purpose, by providing certain parameters we can format the date into required format.