# Restrict String-dates

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-express

I´ve got a Sql-Express database where my C#-application has it´s data from. 
One dataset has name, id, date etc. 
Now, I need to restrict the datasets to a defined timespan.

My problem-solving approach is a Sql-Statement with the BETWEEN keyword. 
For sure, this doesn´t work with String-dates.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings? SQL Server has perfectly good `Date` and `DateTime` data types.

Comment: well convert the strings to date and then apply the limits on these date columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
WHERE CAST(STR_DATE_COL as DATE) BETWEEN ...
```

Here is a [useful list illustrating CONVERT codes for dates](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compose a SQL query using dates as strings you should ensure you are formatting them correctly.

Use the format `YYYYMMDD` to avoid problems with the day and month being reversed.

Have a look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7308203/243925