# ms sql 2005 can't compare dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge database in ms sql. I have a date stored into a field of type: `VARCHAR2`
I have the code, but it can't compare dates. What I mean? There is an input with a launch date. What I need is to get the launchdate inputs where the launchdate is bigger than a date and smaller than another. The problem is that when I change the year from 2012 to 2013 there are no results. Also when I have dates with 0 (like 01.01.2012) it can't compire them.

What I have so far is:

```
edited
```

Can someone help me to get the correct results?

**EDIT1**

The date is stored as string in this format: yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: first why did you stored dates on string (*VARCHAR2*)? why not directy `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Comment: Instead of converting to date and then back to varchar, just convert to date. Better still store dates in datetime columns and don't convert anything.

Comment: @John Woo This is an existing database and I'm trying to get the results out of it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WHERE` clause you are doing a double conversion unnecessarily and actually comparing `VARCHAR` **not** `DATETIME`

To compare `DATETIME` following is enough.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, p11.pa_value,104) >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2012',104)
```

Or you can `CAST`

```
CAST(p11.pa_value AS DATETIME) >= CAST('01.01.2012' AS DATETIME)
```

**EDIT:** I think you need to check for `NULL` values of `[t].PA_NAME` as well

```
ISNULL([t].PA_NAME,'') = 'yourString'  --if you need filter null PA_NAME
ISNULL([t].PA_NAME,'yourString') = 'yourString' --if you need to bring null PA_NAME
```

Comment: there are no results when I run it

Comment: Well, it may be due to something else. Check your query or/and data

Comment: It could be any of those `PA_NAME` are NULL so in that case you can go ISNULL(t.PA_NAME,'') = 'YourString'. Or perhaps you could have them in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
p1.PA_VALUE as Quote_number,
p2.PA_VALUE as Project_Name,
p3.PA_VALUE as requestNumber,
p4.PA_VALUE as reqLocation_CHECK,
p5.PA_VALUE as reqActivityCode,
p6.PA_VALUE as reqSegment,
p7.PA_VALUE as reqTotalPRLocalMargin_CHECK,
p8.PA_VALUE as reqDiscountPerc_CHECK,
p10.PA_VALUE as RequisitionerName,
p11.PA_VALUE as Date_Start,
p13.PA_VALUE as reqTotalPRNetNet_CHECK,
p14.PA_VALUE as reqCustomerNumber,
p15.PA_VALUE as Is_Validated


from WP_WorkflowProcess p 
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p1 on p1.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p1.PA_NAME = 'reqQuoteNumber'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p2 on p2.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p2.PA_NAME = 'reqProjectName'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p3 on p3.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p3.PA_NAME = 'RequestNumber'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p4 on p4.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p4.PA_NAME = 'reqCustomerLocation'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p5 on p5.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p5.PA_NAME = 'reqActivityCode'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p6 on p6.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p6.PA_NAME = 'reqSegment'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p7 on p7.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p7.PA_NAME = 'reqTotalPRLocalMargin'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p8 on p8.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p8.PA_NAME = 'reqDiscountPerc'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p10 on p10.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p10.PA_NAME = 'RequisitionerName'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p11 on p11.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p11.PA_NAME = 'LaunchDate'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p13 on p13.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p13.PA_NAME = 'reqTotalPRNetNet'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p14 on p14.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p14.PA_NAME = 'reqCustomerNumber'
LEFT JOIN PA_PARAMETER p15 on p15.PA_WP_ID=p.WP_ID AND p15.PA_NAME = 'isValidated'


WHERE p.WP_TYPE = 'EnergyMarketing' 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, p11.pa_value) >=  CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.01.2012')
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, p11.pa_value) <=  CONVERT(DATETIME, '01.09.2012')
```

Comment: please, check whether data is availble for giving where condition: like first remove  p.WP_TYPE = 'EnergyMarketing' ..

Comment: and also check data is avillable between '01.01.2012' and '01.09.2012'

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, p11.pa_value, 104) >= CONVERT(datetime, '01.01.2012', 104)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers regarding the multiple data type conversions, be careful about the format of the date your are presenting in your literal strings. On my SQL server (UK region) the date `01.09.2012` is converted to `2012-01-09` (the 9th January).

Your query may not be returning any data as you are only asking for a 9 days worth of data, not 9 months.

Take a look at the comments under [my answer to a sql date problem question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7308203/243925) regarding the date formats to use.