# SQL Server casting error

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is regarding my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176788/ms-sql-2005-cant-compare-dates) topic.

The problem I have is that when the date wich have to be casted is like: (25.09.2012) is throwing a strange error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Here the code is:

```
edited
```

Is there a way to convert it? For example when I put `20.09.2012` im getting an error, but it's running with `10.09.2012` Please help me with this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `GERMAN` (*dd.MM.yyyy*) format, try

```
convert(datetime, '20.09.2012', 104)
```

- **[CAST and CONVERT<sup>[MSDN Doc]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx)**

Comment: opps, [it's working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5646). what rdbms your are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
...
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), p11.pa_value, 121) >= 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '01.04.2012', 121)
```

Comment: @Slim - Try `CONVERT(DATETIME, '20120401', 121)`